# Display content/node date in calendar instead of text

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom content type that ask for a date range from users. How do I display the date in Calendar format instead of just plain text?

the format should be like this.

||Selected Date Range displayed in Calendar||

||Content Title||

||Content Body||

and so on. I am using drupal 7.

Comment: By display, do you mean on node page view? However, you can use date popup to dispaly a popup calendar when entering the dates!

Comment: i mean the page view in the "Manage Display". After the content has been published.

Answer (score 0):

The [Calendar Block](https://drupal.org/project/calendar_block) module shoudl give you what you need.

Comment: sorry, that seems like not an actively maintained module and there is only dev release for drupal 7.